# perl fail to get memcache array

Tags: perl, memcached

I new to perl and working on a code with php and perl.

I store an array with php into memcache

```
$key = 'mytest';
$m = new Memcache;
$m->connect( CACHE_HOST, CACHE_PORT );
$myval = array('a'=>'apple');
$mval = $m->set( $key, $myval );
$mval = $m->get( $key );
print_r($mval);
print "\n";
```

However I fail to retrieve it using perl. but it work well if `$myval` is a non-array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Cache::Memcached::Fast;

my $memd = new Cache::Memcached::Fast({ 
    servers => [ { address => 'CACHE_HOST:CACHE_PORT ' }, ], 
    });

#my $val = $memd->get("mytest");
#print Dumper($val);
my @val = $memd->get("mytest");
print Dumper(\@val);
```

How can I retrieve the array?

Comment: You aren't doing any error checking to see if the connection was successful...

Comment: Connection is good. I have not problem when `$myval` in php is a string: `$myval = 'apple';`

Comment: How do you know that the connection is good?  There's no error checking in your code to validate that the connection didn't fail.

Comment: I able to get return from memcache when it's store string; I unable to get return value when it store an array

Answer (score 1):

I've never used memcached, but a couple of possibilities that come to mind are:

1. Since the array you created in the PHP script has a non-integer key you may need to retrieve the object as a hash, rather than an array, in the perl script. So try using `my %val = $memd->get("mytest");` instead of `my @val = ...`
2. Perhaps the return value of `$memd->get("mytest")` needs to be [de-referenced](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/using_perl/dereferencing.html)?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the same as in [Perl arrays in memcached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665365/perl-arrays-in-memcached/20382988#20382988) please have a look at my answer at the page mentioned where
In perl On can get the cache values like

```
my $serviceID=$ARGV[0];
my $perlKey=’perl_’.$serviceID;
my $result = $memcli->get($perlKey);
```

and to set memcache you can use

```
$perlString = $val1.’,’. $val2.’,’. $val3.’,’. $val4.’,’. $val5.’,’. $val6;
$memcache->set($perlKey, $perlString, 0, 10);
```

- See more at: http://ecarobar.com/memcached-using-php-and-perl/

Comment: or use some serialization format understood by both php and perl, such as JSON.